# Save body text to temp file in Formidable

Tags: javascript, node.js, formidable

I have a text field in the `fields` parameter of the form that I want to write to a file and save to the temp directory, similar to how Formidable handles file uploads. Does Formidable have methods to access its temp file writing capabilities?

Example:

`tempFile = writeToTempFile(fields.textField)`
`files.tempFile = tempFile`